# CSS2DRenderer not in Three.js

Tags: reactjs, three.js

Some context first :

I installed three.js in a default react project with npm, and I would like to implement [this example](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/examples/css2d_label.html) that uses CSS2D.

However I get this error when creating a new instance of the renderer:

"export 'CSS2DRenderer' (imported as 'THREE') was not found in 'three'.

After looking into the node module, I concluded the issue was that three.js doesn't include CSS2DRenderer in its build, but I may be wrong.

I'm quite new at this and would like to know if it's possible to add that renderer when installing three.js.

I'm open to suggestions or workarounds, all I want is to keep 'fixed' labels in a 3d scene.

Also this is my first post ever, if I can improve my posts in any way please advise me :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right, `CSS2DRenderer` is no part of the library core. If you want to use the renderer, you have to transfer `CSS2DRenderer` into a separate module. You might want to have a look at the following issue at github in order to check out different approaches for this.

https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/9562

Comment: Please accept/upvote the answer if it was useful to you.

Comment: This thread helped me to discover [link](https://github.com/Itee/three-full) which allows you to use Three.js examples as ES6 module. This is the solution I'll use. Thanks.